# Best way to display massive PDF on webpage

Tags: html, pdf, web

My company is looking to create a page for an accreditation document which is several hundred pages long. There are about five sections, each with roughly 40-70 pages.

What do you think is the best way to handle navigation and display for this? Currently the only thing I've got in my mind is a simple nav window on the left that directs to iframes of each section's PDF and lets Adobe's table of contents manage navigation from there.

OR I could make each section in the nav a drop-down and each subsection a separate PDF (to reduce load times), but that feels clunky.

Large PDFs are nice as there is less page jumping, but they have awful load times. Small PDFs are nice for the fast load times, but awful with jumping around.

Any ideas would be appreciated. I'm left scratching my head on this one.

Comment: I think for people who have to read 350 pages of legal mumbo jumbo, a 30 second loading time is the least of their problems. I'd make it one document, and make it easily downloadable, so they can read it on their e-reader or print it if they like.

Comment: By that you mean nix the "web navigation" all together and just use Adobe's native navigation all available offline? That probably would be easiest. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

We've server-side pdf-to-png converters for that. 
The webpage is loading page by page as png-image via AJAX while scrolling.

Works like a charm.

Comment: Now that's an interesting concept. How does it display? Still in the acrobat reader iframe?

Comment: No, the client just receives images. No PDF at all. The images are loaded via AJAX on-the-fly while scrolling the webpage. One image per page. No acrobat required. Works with every browser out-of-the-box even on mobile with low bandwith. But you loose some functions from Acrobat like "search".

Comment: Sounds awesome! I'll have to look into that. Thanks for the idea :)

Comment: if pay solution is suitable, then I can recommend [pdfium.net.sdk](http://pdfium.patagames.com). for this task it would be perfect

Answer (score 1):

On the PDF side, make sure that your document is optimized for fast web view. This would transfer the first page plus all the overhead, and then only transfer the pages which are requested.

Conditions for that is that the server supports byteserving (something any kind of new webserver should be able to do), and that the PDF viewer component used to display the PDF understands about byteserving (the Acrobat/Reader component does, for example).

For the navigation, you could use bookmarks, which you make displaying in the document options of the document. With a good set of bookmarks, navigation through the document becomes rather easy.

Answer (score 0):

It is big PDF. Navigation is fine but you want that user should not download the pdf and each time they have to read from site. Second case is when many users are not interested complete the PDF file, They may download/read particular section.

As per my view you should break PDF in smaller section and  sections should managed by navigation links.